# Wpf detect when window is closed from a different window

Tags: c#, wpf

```
   private void newmail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Nieuweemail _nieuweEmail = new Nieuweemail(_username);
        _nieuweEmail.Show();
    }
```

When that window is closed, I want to call a function inside my main window that will execute.

```
        _nieuweEmail.Closed += setContent();
```

I could do this if I could call it in the window that is going to be closed. But that's not the case. How can I detect this?

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to call `setContent();` when the window is closed?

Comment: It doesn't work, haha :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `setContent` and `newmail_Click` are both methods in your main window...

```
private void newmail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Nieuweemail _nieuweEmail = new Nieuweemail(_username);
    _nieuweEmail.Closed += SetContentHandler;
    _nieuweEmail.Show();
}

private void SetContentHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setContent();
}
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type void to System.eventhandler

Comment: @user3227070 I think you need to change `_nieuweEmail.Closed += setContent();` to `_nieuweEmail.Closed += setContent;`

Comment: No overload for setContent matches delegate Eventhandler

Comment: Yes, take the () out after SetContent and ensure SetContent is an appropriate event handler. Or, call your SetContent method from the event handler. I'm updating my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I was just a private void function, hence why it wasn't working. Thanks :)

Comment: You're very welcome. Thanks for the opportunity to help!